# How to move a div inside <ul> on top of <li>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck in this situation where I have to move a div inside the List. I tried appendChlid and insertBefore but I can't seem to make it work. The code is as following:

```html
<div class='error'>Content</div>
  <div class='form'>
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I want the result to look like:

```html
  <div class='form'>
    <ul>
      <div class='error'>Content</div>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

What is the best way to make this work?

Comment: The HTMLyou are aiming for is not valid. Could you therefore describe what effect you want so we can see how best to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible because *ul* does not allow *div* elements.

> Permitted content: Zero or more *li*, *script* and *template* elements.

See:　https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='error'>Content</div>
   <div class='form'>
   <ul>
      <li id="first-li">Item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
$('.error').insertBefore('#first-li');
```

Hope this help.